# Create your own hash in PHP?

Tags: php, hash

Well, I need to save images with unique filenames and store the file names in the database. I used to do MD5 hash and save the image with the filename of value obtained by hash.

However I would like to cut down the unnecessary space usage from 32 characters to 10-12 characters.

I dont want to substr() the obtained md5 hash to 12 characters.

Rather than that is there a way to create a custom hash of 10-12 characters ?

Comment: You can represent a 128 Bit MD5 hash value with 16 characters.

Comment: Please notice you *still* have to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent the 128 Bit MD5 hash values with just 16 characters (8 bit per character instead of just 4).

Comment: Example: 1 byte = 1 character. 128 bit = 16 byte. => 128 bit = 16 characters. `md5("string", true)` delivers 16 characters. **Beware!** The string will also contain \0 and such.

Comment: Would it be safe to insert the same value in a mysql database (utf-8 collation) or do i need to perform an filters?

Comment: @atif089: Better use BINARY ASCII as the characters ≥ 128 use more than one byte in UTF-8. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504268

Comment: echo md5('1_DSC00144_' . time(), true); returns me "ƒ|^×íñu¬‹_ë õòþ", I need to use an ASCII string to save in the database so that I can use it in the URL.  bin2hex is making it back to 32 characters once again.

Comment: Yes, that's the deal, when you only use the upper 64bit of ASCII ;-)

Comment: LoL, using **crc32b** as of now. But there should be something more appropriate as well like most of the image hosting website, facebook, and orkut use.. Will do some research :)

Comment: @atif089: You could then use 6 Bits instead and use the characters Base64 does.

Comment: Quote from OP's comment: "I need to use an ASCII string to save in the database so that I can use it in the URL". Why don't you just set DB table to UTF-8 and use URL-encoding? After all it sounds like that you aren't really aware about the relationship between bytes/bits and characters and the encoding story. I'd suggest to do a bit more research on that area.

Comment: @BalusC: UTF-8 would use more than just one byte for the characters ≥ 128. Plain binary ASCII is better.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the following function Tempnam

http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

"Creates a file with a unique filename, with access permission set to 0600, in the specified directory. If the directory does not exist, `tempnam()` may generate a file in the system's temporary directory, and return the name of that. "

Comment: I don't actually want to create a file, I want to move an uploaded file with a unique name to a directory. Taking this function into consideration, I will have to create a tmp file, read uploaded file, overwrite tmp file. Wouldn't you think it will be slower complared to just moving a file from one location to another ?

Comment: Depending on the size of the files and the regularity of the uploads, the extra overhead should be minimal

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using CRC32 instead of MD5? It is 8 characters, not 32, but it is nearer to your goal.

Comment: yeah so its 26 ^ 8 in all .. i guess its enough

Comment: but I dont want them to collide thats the reason I am looking for 10-12 characters

Answer (score 1):

[PHP's Hash message digest framework](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) provides tons of hash algorithms. Have fun!

To determine each hash's length, [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions).

Answer (score 1):

[CRC32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) is 8 ASCII characters long.

Comment: CRC32 is a checksum - not really a hash. Almost every 50K crc32(), you get a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I made this simple hash function to create my own hash with custom characters and size

```
function simple_hash($str, $size=5, $characters='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {
    $hash_array = array();
    $hash = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
        $hash_array[$i]=0;
    }
    for($s=0;$s<strlen($str);$s++){
        for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
            $hash_array[$i]=($hash_array[$i]+ord($str[$s])+$i+$s+$size)%strlen($characters);
        }
    }
    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
        $hash .= $characters[$hash_array[$i]];
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

How to use:

```
<?=simple_hash('test')?>  // EIMQU
<?=simple_hash('test')?>  // EIMQU
<?=simple_hash('test',10)?> // Y26aeimquy
<?=simple_hash('test',10)?> // Y26aeimquy
<?=simple_hash('test',10,'abcdefghijkl')?> // cgkcgkcgkc
<?=simple_hash('test',10,'abcdeABCDE')?> // eDcBaeDcBa

<?=simple_hash('test2')?>  // BGLQV 
<?=simple_hash('test3')?>  // CHMRW
<?=simple_hash('a big string')?> // gsEQ2
<?=simple_hash('Ελληνικά')?> // 0gwM2
<?=simple_hash('Ελληνικα')?> // 5lBR7
```